# VNC Viewer shows weird colours when connected to OSX

Tags: mac, vnc

I am using RealVNC server Enterprise on the Mac.

Real VNC Enterprise Viewer on PC.

I am able to connect it properly but colors are weird, 16 colors or only blue color is showing up (see below)

[image: Oh the blue!]

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a VNC viewer you need to ensure you use protocol v3.3 when connecting to a Mac. Version 4.x will, at best, give unreliable results.

One application I've found that works well for VNC, RDP and a bunch of other protocols is [Terminals](http://www.codeplex.com/Terminals). I have mine set up with shortcuts to each of the servers, wither they be Windows or Mac. With its tabbed windows life gets to be just a little bit easier.

Comment: I installed terminals , That didn't worked. And evn my other VNC are also not working now. The Screen opens and then automatically closes.

How can i uninstall terminals

Answer (score 1):

The Mac wouldn't happen to be an XServe, would it?  If so, connect to the Lights-Out-Management (or LOM) address instead of the OS's IP.  I've seen this behavior before and that was the solution.